# how to delete particular number of rows in a table using php

Tags: php, mysql

if i select these particular rows using

```
select * from wp_posts where title like 'abc%'
```

it displays the rows
now i want to delete these rows using php
Can i do this or iam wrong
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It would be more interesting if you inform your code a little more complete. But basically the SQL command is as follows:

```
delete from wp_posts where title like 'abc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is sensitive data like activation keys or something, you need to use binary function of mysql to check whether abc is matching with ABC or not.

Use this one:

```
delete from wp_posts where title like binary('ABC%')
```

Comment: The author said it is already showing what you want to delete. This specification is unnecessary for the question.